# How could I make a scalable computer out of multiple single-board computers?

Tags: linux, motherboard, python, computer-building

I've been looking into getting a [C.H.I.P.](https://getchip.com/pages/chip) single-board computer (think a cheap Raspberry Pi) to use as a decently cheap Python dev environment, but I'd like more power. I've considered getting a couple and using them as a single machine.

I'm looking for a way to do this. Preferably, I could also incorporate an external hard drive and even keep the multi-CHIP unit itself in a small, portable box to be hooked up to monitors as needed (with a portable battery to boot), or access it remotely from web-capable devices. I've considered making something similar to one of many Raspberry Pi supercomputers out there, but rather than keeping the computers as separate nodes connected to a router, they would just be different parts of a single box. This design would also ideally be easily scalable, i.e. I can add more CHIPs without too much effort, to an extent.

First: Is this possible? Could I use multiple single-board PCs as components of one, more powerful PC?

Second: If so, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends.  Lets talk about what you mean by "more power".  If you imagine your typical computer you have a cpu doing the work connected to a high speed memory store and one or more lower speed I/O devices: disk, network, USB etc.  With a CHIP you have all this too.  Now if you add a second unit, that doesnt make the collection a faster computer unless you also come up with a way to make CPU 2 access the memory/storage of CPU 1 at the same rate as the latter.  This is why large computer designers get all excited about QPI and Infiniband and so on.

The other definition of power treats each computer (CHIP in your case) as distinct and measures in the aggregate.  This requires that the software you run is capable of being decomposed to run on multiple independent nodes at once.  That is, it is cluster or pool friendly or parallelizable (or can be made so). Depending on what yiu arr trying to do with your software, this may or may not be possible.

Finally, fwiw, a number of people have demonstrated small RPi clusters running software and orchestrated by Kubernetes.  Thia might be a good place to start in the cluster space if you are interested.

Comment: The former most accurately captures my goal.